# The screen is redrawn when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuex

I am creating a process that modals when I click the watch wallet button.

I can show or hide modals, but the screen is rendered when I click the show button.

When I check the console in console.log ('Clicked'), it is displayed, but the screen is rendered and disappears immediately.

What is the cause?

↓ Home.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="login-message-area">
      <div>
        <span>{{ updateUserName }}Welcome！！</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <span>残高 : 1000</span>
        <button @click="logOut">LogOut</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h1>ユーザ一覧</h1>

    <div class="user-list-wrapper">
      <h4>ユーザ名</h4>

      <ul class="user-list">
        <li>
          <span>TEST</span>
          <form>
            <button @click="openModal">watch wallet</button>
            <button>Send</button>
          </form>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>TEST</span>
          <form>
            <button　@click="openModal">watch wallet</button>
            <button>Send</button>
          </form>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>TEST</span>
          <form>
            <button　@click="openModal">watch wallet</button>
            <button>Send</button>
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="overlay" v-show="showContent" @click="closeModal">
      <div class="content">
        <p>Balance</p>
        <p>5,000Yen</p>
        <p><button @click="closeModal">Close</button></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
        showContent: true
    };
  },
  computed: {
    updateUserName() {
      return this.$store.getters.updateUserName
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('updateUserName');
  },
  methods: {
    async logOut() {
        await this.$store.dispatch('logOut');
        this.$router.push('/');
    },
    openModal() {
      this.showContent = true
      console.log('Clicked');
    },
    closeModal() {
      this.showContent = false
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

↓store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const store = createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      userName: '',
      updateUserName: '',
      userLoginInfomation: '',
      errorMessage: ''

    };
  },
  getters: {
    getUserName: (state) => state.userName,
    updateUserName: (state) => state.updateUserName,
  },
  mutations: {
    setUserName(state, user) {
      state.userName = user.displayName;
    },
    updateUserName(state, updateUserName) {
      state.updateUserName = updateUserName;
    },
    userLoginInfomation(state, userLoginInfomation) {
        state.userLoginInfomation = userLoginInfomation
    },
    setErrorMessage(state, errorMessage) {
      state.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async signUp({ commit }, userInfomation) {
      try {
        await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userInfomation.email,userInfomation.password);
        const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        await user.updateProfile({
          displayName: userInfomation.username,
        });
        commit('setUserName', user);
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
      }
    },
    updateUserName({ commit }) {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          commit('updateUserName', user.displayName);
        }
      });
    },
    async login({ commit }, userInfomation) {
        commit('userLoginInfomation', userInfomation);
        try {
            await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userInfomation.email,userInfomation.password);
      } catch (e) {
            commit('setErrorMessage', e.message);
            alert(e.message);
      }
    },
    async logOut({ commit }) {
        try {
            await firebase.auth().signOut();
        } catch(e) {
            commit('setErrorMessage', e.message);
            alert(e.message);
        }
      }
  },
});

export default store;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `type="button"` to your buttons.

As you are using `<form>` and **button** inside it without any type, it is behaving like `type ="submit"` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Add preventDefault to your @click event. Something like below. Or you can add type="button" to prevent page submit.

```
@click.prevent="showmodal"
```

Same will be go for all @click events.